# Sorting String Array Indicies with Insertion Sort, Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am working on an assignment where I have to sort an array and store the indices in a doubly linked list ADT that I have built.

```
Example:
{"A","B","C","A"} -> {0,3,1,2}
```

My current approach is to bring the indices into my ADT and then sort the ADT as I sort the array. As far as I can tell, I am doing the exact same operation on both the array and the doubly linked list every time either loop executes, but my output does not match up.

```
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    List A = new List();
    String[] inputArray = {"A","C","B","A"};
    int i,j;
    String key;
    //load indices into doubly-linked list
    for (int x = 0; x < inputArray.length; x++ ) {
        A.append(x);
    }
    //begin insertion sort
    for (j = 1; j < inputArray.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(A);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
        key = inputArray[j];
        i = j - 1;
        while (i >= 0) {
            if (key.compareTo(inputArray[i]) > 0) {
                break;
            }
            inputArray[i+1] = inputArray[i];
            //moveTo moves the cursor to <int>
            A.moveTo(i);
            //make sure we aren't trying to insert before first node
            if (i > 0) { A.insertBefore(i+1); }
            else { A.prepend(i+1); }
            //remove node at cursor
            A.delete();
            i--;
        }
        inputArray[i+1] = key;
        A.moveTo(i+1);
        if (i > 0) { A.insertBefore(i+1); }
        else { A.prepend(i+1); }
        A.delete();
    }
    System.out.println(A);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
}
```

The above code gives the following output:

run:
0 1 2 3
[A, C, B, A]
1 0 2 3
[A, C, B, A]
1 1 2 3
[A, B, C, A]
0 2 3 3
[A, A, B, C]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

EDIT: List.java

```
public class List {

    private class Node{
        //Fields
        int data;
        Node next, previous;
        //Constructor
        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
            previous = null;
        }
        public String toString() { return String.valueOf(data); }
    }

    //Fields
    private Node frontNode, backNode, cursorNode;
    private int totalSize, cursorPosition;

    //Constructor
    List() {
        frontNode = backNode = cursorNode = null;
        totalSize = 0;
        cursorPosition = -1;
    }
    //moveTo(int i): If 0<=i<=length()-1, moves the cursor to the element 
    // at index i, otherwise the cursor becomes undefined.
    void moveTo(int i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            cursorPosition = i;
            cursorNode = frontNode;
        }
        else if (i == length() - 1) {
            cursorPosition = i;
            cursorNode = backNode;
        }
        else if (i > 0 && i < length() - 1 ) {
            cursorNode = frontNode;
            cursorPosition = i;
            for (int x=0; x < i; x++) {
                cursorNode = cursorNode.next;
            }
        }
        else {
            cursorPosition = -1; 
        }
    }

//prepend(int data): Inserts new element before front element in this List.
    void prepend(int data) {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        if ( this.length() == 0 ) {
            frontNode = backNode = node;
        }
        else {
            frontNode.previous = node;
            node.next = frontNode;
            frontNode = node;
        }
        totalSize++;
        //cursorPosition might change?
    }
    //insertBefore(int data): Inserts new element before cursor element in this
    // List. Pre: length()>0, getIndex()>=0
    void insertBefore(int data) {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        if ( this.length() > 0 && this.getIndex() >= 0 ) {
            node.previous = cursorNode.previous;
            node.next = cursorNode;
            cursorNode.previous.next = node;
            cursorNode.previous = node;
            totalSize++;
        }
        else if ( this.length() <= 0 )
        {
           throw new RuntimeException
                    ("Error: insertBefore called on empty list");
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException
                    ("Error: insertBefore called without cursor set");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what your List class is, but it doesn't seem to be something in the standard Java runtime.  Since we don't know what it is or what, exactly, the methods in it are supposed to do, or whether the List methods are even working correctly, I don't see how we can help at all.

Comment: I can include the code, but I figured since it is over 300 lines people wouldn't want it. It implements a doubly linked list. I will edit the original post to include the relevant portions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks.  I didn't know exactly what insertBefore() and prepend() were intended to do (I could have guessed, but programming should not be about guessing what methods are supposed to do; seeing the documentation is much better).

Since this is an assignment, I'm not going to give you the answer.  But the clue is this: After the first pass through the loop, the dump of A gives you the same indices you started with, but rearranged.  I think that's the way it's supposed to be after every loop iteration.  But that's not true after the second pass through the loop (1 shows up twice, and 0 is gone).  Think about it.  When you called A.insertBefore() to rearrange the elements of A, what data *should* you have told insertBefore() to insert, and what did you actually insert?

Comment: I have been working on this since I posted, and you are right, but I am still struggling. I had already realized that sending i into A makes no sense. I want to be sending the original position of the data point, which is related to both inputArray.length as well as j.

However, I haven't figured out the correct relationship yet.

Thanks for the help and sorry for the incomplete question at first.

Comment: Remember, you're just rearranging the data in A.